# I get Invalid parameter with this icacls line

Tags: windows, security, ntfs

icacls d:\users\dptname\username /grant:W company-domain\username:(OI)(CI)(M)

error says: invalid paramter "/grant:W"

why?

Comment: /grant:w is apparently not correct. you can either use /grant or /grant:r. If you intent to give the user write-only permissions place it like `company-domain\username:(OI)(CI)W`

Answer (score 1):

```
grant:W
```

is not valid because the only valid switch is

> grant:r

or no switch at all.  From the documentation

> With :r the permissions replace any previously granted explicit permissions.
>   Without :r the permissions are added to any previously granted explicit permissions

Answer (score -2):

I got it. company-domain\username should be in quotation marks...